# Coldfusion show all included files on load

Tags: coldfusion

I recently took over a site that is a complete and utter disaster.  Very bad code and broken every time I turn around.  My question is, with ColdFusion, how can I show/display every page that is included in a page.  This site has includes within includes within includes.  Naming conventions are terrible, with thousands of lines of code in each. No variables passed in page urls...I mean seriously, I can go on and on.  I just need to know all the pages that are included when a specific page loads so I know where to look for the problem.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such functionality, however, when an error occurs, there should be a tag context that is somewhat like a stack trace in that it will show you how to get to the file, including the includes leading to it.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the `Enable Request Debugging Output` in your ColdFusion Administrator. This settings is located in the `Debug Output Settings` section. Then turn on `Report Execution Times`. This will output all the files used to build the page and the time each template took at the bottom of your page.

More information from the documentation:

[CF10 Debug Settings Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff8)

[CF9 Debug Settings Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7ff8)

Comment: look at `\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\debug\classic.cfm` you can copy code from there to `onRequestEnd`

Comment: This is probably the best/easiest way to get the information for which you are looking, but I would strongly advise you NOT to do this on a production server.

Answer (score 3):

I found a related comment on Ben Nadel's blog from Roger Tubby in 2011:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/116-finding-template-execution-stack-in-coldfusion.htm#comments_36939

This method doesn't require enabling debugging or configuring any IP address.  Calling the `java.lang.Exception` java class will return an object with a `TagContext` key that contains an array of structs (in reverse order) that will identify template files & lines of execution, but not execution times.

```
<cfscript>
JavaException = createObject("java","java.lang.Exception").init();
writedump(JavaException.TagContext);
</cfscript>
```

Here's a screenshot of a sample dump of the `TagContext` array.
[image]

Comment: I just tested this and it continues to work w/ColdFusion 2016.

Comment: I'm migrating some projects to Lucee and "TagContext" doesn't exist and will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on others' answers, the following code will dump out included templates, and who included them.

For this to work, you need to check **Enable Request Debugging Output** in CFAdmin > Debug Output Settings

```
<cfobject action="CREATE" type="JAVA" class="coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory" name="factory">
<cfset cfdebugger = factory.getDebuggingService()>
<cfset qEvents = cfdebugger.getDebugger().getData()>

<cfquery dbType="query" name="cfdebug_templates" debug="false">
    SELECT template, parent, Sum(endTime - StartTime) AS et
    FROM qEvents
    WHERE type = 'Template'
    GROUP BY template, parent
    ORDER BY et DESC
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#cfdebug_templates#">
```

Comment: This one looked nice, but when I tried it, I got an error.  I traced it and found that getDebugger() was coming back as undefined.
This was with CF 11.

Comment: And it was with Request Debugging Output as on, and cf service had just been restarted.